# inconsistency with stereo calibration using camera calibration toolbox MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

I have been trying to do a stereo calibration with the Matlab camera calibration toolbox.  I have two cameras being triggered at the same time, and I'm grabbing corners from 25 pairs of images.  The individual calibrations are working, though one camera calibration uses only 24 of the 25 images (when I `reproject on images`, only 24 images pop up.  When I try to use the L and R calibration.mat files for a stereo calibration, it throws `Disabling view XX - L and R views are found inconsistent` for every single pair (and it says there are only 24 pairs of images, not 25).  I've read the help file but I don't think that it addresses my problem.  Please advise!

Comment: I learned that things work out better if I manually load the `calib_data.mat` file when I re-visit my individual calibrations than they do if I follow the instructions and load the `calib_results.mat` file.  I do this for each camera, then use them for stereo calibration - it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the [CameraCalibrator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/find-camera-parameters-with-the-camera-calibrator.html) App that is a part of the Computer Vision System Toolbox for MATLAB.  It gives you a very easy way to calibrate a single camera, including automatic checkerboard detection. It does not let calibrate a stereo pair, but it gets you half-way there.